# Extract zipcodes from string and build a select statement in php

Tags: php, string, text-extraction

I have a string that I grab from my DB which has town and zipcode information in it. I want to extract the zipcodes (always 5 digits) from it and build a select statement from it  (using PHP) as follows:

```
$townZip = 'Boston(02108, 02112, 02116), Chelsea (02150), Revere (02151)';

<select>
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="02108">02108</option>
  <option value="02112">02112</option>
  <option value="02116">02116</option>
  <option value="02150">02150</option>
  <option value="02151">02151</option>
</select>
```

Please note that the string can have varying number of towns, zipcodes so that solution has to be flexible enough to accomodate this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Yoshi - I tinkered around with explode a bit but coudln't get it to work. I should have posted what I tried in my original question. My bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $townZip = 'Boston(02108, 02112, 02116), Chelsea (02150), Revere (02151)';

    $zips = explode(',',preg_replace('#[^,0-9]#', '', $townZip));

    echo '<select>';
    echo '<option value="">Please Select</option>';
    foreach($zips as $zip){
        echo '<option value="'. $zip.'">'. $zip.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

The above code removes everything except numbers and comma, then explodes it with the comma which gives the zipcodes you need. Then loop through the array of zipcodes and create select.

**[UPDATED]**

It will look a bit messy but you can achieve town names with zipcodes with the following:

```
<?php
    $townZip = 'Boston(02108, 02112, 02116), Chelsea (02150), Revere (02151)';

    $zips = explode(',',preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z,0-9(]#', '', $townZip));

    echo '<select>';
    echo '<option value="">Please Select</option>';
    $prev = '';
    foreach($zips as $zip){
        $temp = explode('(',$zip);
        if(isset($temp[1])){
            $prev = $temp[0];
            $temp[0] = $temp[1];
        }   
        echo '<option value="'. $temp[0].'">'. $prev. '-' . $temp[0].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Think Different! This works great. Really appreciate it. Is there a way to tweak this to include the town name in the option e.g. <option value="02116">Boston - 02116</option>

Comment: Thanks again @Think Different. The solution with town names while involved works just as great. Appreciate it!